# Quickbooks Causing RDP disconnects

Tags: remote-desktop-services

I run about 20 Windows 2016/2019 RDP Servers out of a central datacenter. I have a group of 4 QuickBooks (21 Enterprise) users on a fully patched 2019 server that are experiencing frequent RDP disconnects from the Terminal Server they share. Users of other servers are unaffected.

Some users are in the office and RDP over VPN to the QB server, some access the server from home, again RDP over VPN. (IPSEC)

Disconnects are usually accompanied by a "Because of an error in data encryption, this session will end", however sometimes we just get a non-responsive session. The weird thing is that this issue is entirely associated with specific QuickBooks activities, but not frequently enough to be directly replicable.
Printing invoices (to rdp redirected printer)
Saving a new invoice
Launching a report
Opening a saved QB invoice

Its causing a significant impact on business so I need to get this solved.
Some answers to questions I foresee:

- No packet loss from any user machines
- No significant latency
- We have disabled UDP for RDP. This actually appears to have resolved the issue for one user, but it did not for the others.
- Users only disconnect when doing QuickBooks related tasks, however after reconnecting RDP the QuickBooks session itself is fine.
- No vpn disconnect and mapped drive to that server stays connected

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On the RD Session Host, open RD Session Host Configuration.
Open RDP-Tcp configuration page.
In General tab, low down the Security Layer to RDP Security Layer.
Click OK to save the setting.
Then, try to reconnect to the server from the problematic Windows clients.